# Use a macro in SAS 'to_date' conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

Being forced to pass my code in explicit pass though, the date conversion no longer works.
I would like to use the &aaaa macro in the convert function.

My code example :

```
%let aaaa = 2014;
proc sql;
EXECUTE(
create table new_table as (
select * from old_table
where date between to_date('01/01/&aaaa', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('01/01/&aaaa', 'dd/mm/yyyy')))
BY ORACLE;
```

I got an error :

> "The (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and be different from 0".

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Macro variables only resolve in double quotes not single quotes so you'll have to change that. IIRC Oracle has issues with to_date but you can also provide the dates as : DATE '2020-01-01' but I'd consider making the whole variable, including the quotes your macro variable just to make it a bit easier.

Comment: Oracle has issues with values in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro variables only resolve in double quotes not single quotes so you'll have to change that. IIRC Oracle has issues with to_date but you can also provide the dates as : DATE '2020-01-01' but I'd consider making the whole variable, including the quotes your macro variable just to make it a bit easier.

```
%let aaaa = '2014-01-01';

proc sql;
EXECUTE(
create table new_table as (
select * from old_table
where date between DATE &aaaa. and DATE &aaaa.))
BY ORACLE;
```

You can modify your original macro variable, aaaa to be in the format below if required.
Untested:

```
%let bbbb = %sysfunc(quote(&aaaa-01-01, "'"));
%put &bbbb.;
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help ! I got an "not valid identificator : '2014-01-01' " arror by using to_date and a ORA-00936 : missing expression by using DATE &aaaa..

Answer (score 0):

I got an :

- "ORACLE execute error: ORA-00904 : '2014-01-01' : not valid identificator " error by using `to_date(&bbbb., 'dd/mm/yyyy')` and
- ORA-00936 : missing expression error by using `DATE &aaaa.`

Comment: Your to_date format specified is dd/mm/yy but you passed in a yy-mm-dd value?

Comment: Indeed, it works well now. Thanks for your support !